# Conectar señales usando GObjectIntrospection

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

Estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builder.html) sobre `python` + `GObjectIntrospection`. El código es muy simple:

```
import gi
gi.require_version( 'Gtk', '3.0' )
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler:
 def onButtonPressed( self, button ):
  print( 'Boton pulsado ... ' )

 def onDestroy( self, *args ):
  Gtk.main_quit( )

builder = Gtk.Builder( )
builder.add_from_file( '.archivo.glade' )

builder.connect_signals( Handler( ) )
window = builder.get_object( 'MainWindow' )
window.show_all( )

Gtk.main( )
```

Al ejecutarlo con `python3 main.py`, aparenta ejecutarse bien, pero al cerrar la ventana (pulsando en el icono de su barra de título), dicha ventana efectivamente se cierra, pero el programa **no finaliza**. Da la sensación de que no se llama a la función `Gtk.main_quit( )`.

En el depurador, colocando un punto de interrupción en la línea

```
Gtk.main_quit( )
```

observo que **nunca se entra** en ese punto. La ejecución no llega ahí. Da la sensación de que `onDestroy` no es la señal a la que conectarse.

Por supuesto, he intentado cambiarlo a 'destroy', 'on_destroy', 'Destroy', y alguna mas, pero ninguna ha funcionado.

Comment: No conozco ese framework, pero por lo que he podido ver en varios ejemplos que lo usan, parece como que la señal "destroy" no se auto-mapea por introspección, sino que debe hacerse explícitamente, con algo como `builder.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)`

Comment: @abulafia Gracias, pero tampoco. Genera el error `unknown signal name: destroy`. He probado también con `'onDestroy'` y `'on_destroy'`, con el mismo resultado. He conseguido hacerlo llamando directamente a `window.connect( 'destroy', ... )` pero así solo puedo conectar señales de una en una. Tiene que haber alguna forma de conectar varias a la vez, usando un *mapa* o una instancia de clase ... pero no doy con la *tecla* :-(

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de declarar las señales en Glade. El mismo tutorial muestra que el archivo .glade se debe cambiar para definir las señales `onDestroy` y `onButtonPressed`:

```
...
    <signal name="destroy" handler="onDestroy" swapped="no"/>
...
        <signal name="pressed" handler="onButtonPressed" swapped="no"/>
...
```

En [este diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/1YloYbu4) se pueden observar en detalle las diferencias entre los dos ejemplos de archivo .glade del tutorial.